# "Not a legal OleAut date" BulkCopy/ Excel 2013 - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, excel-2013, sqlbulkcopy

I am developing an application that will export Excel information into SQL Server. I am using the `SqlBulkCopy`, but I am facing with this error

> Not a legal OleAut date

just on some computers. I already looking for a solution, but it is very hard. I think the problem is because date information from excel. I tried to add one line on Excel with text and upload all information as text, but the date is uploaded as "#######". Please could someone help me with this problem?

```vb
Public Shared Sub ImportDataFromExcel_DAL(ByVal excelFilePath As String)

    'Select From Excel
    Dim ExcelDataQuery As String
    ExcelDataQuery = "SELECT [CustomerPO] ,[Line] ,[Sign Date]  FROM [Sheet1$]  WHERE [CustomerPO] IS NOT NULL"

    'Excel Connection
    Dim sExcelConnectionString As String = (Convert.ToString("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;data source=") & excelFilePath) + ";extended properties=" + """excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;hdr=yes;"""
    Dim odDataReader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim oledbConn As New OleDbConnection(sExcelConnectionString)
    Dim oledbCmd As New OleDbCommand(ExcelDataQuery, oledbConn)
    oledbConn.Open()

    'Execute Excel Query
    odDataReader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()

    'DB Connection open
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection("DB ConnectionString")
    Conn.Open()

    Dim bulkcopy As New SqlBulkCopy(Conn)
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Customer"

    'Mapping the columns
    Dim mapCustomerPONum = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(0, "CustomerPONum")
    Dim mapLineNum = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(1, "LineNum")
    Dim mapSignDate = New SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(2, "SignDate")

    'Add on BulkCopy
    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapCustomerPONum)
    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapLineNum)
    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(mapSignDate)
    bulkcopy.BatchSize = 10000
    bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 180
    bulkcopy.NotifyAfter = 50000

    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(odDataReader) '---- ERROR RETURN HERE ----
    bulkcopy.Close()

End Sub
```

The exception error

```
Not a legal OleAut date.

stack:   at System.DateTime.DoubleDateToTicks(Double value)
   at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.Value_DATE()
   at System.Data.OleDb.ColumnBinding.Value()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.GetValueFromSourceRow(Int32 destRowIndex, Boolean& isSqlType, Boolean& isDataFeed, Boolean& isNull)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ReadWriteColumnValueAsync(Int32 col)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyColumnsAsync(Int32 col, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyRowsAsync(Int32 rowsSoFar, Int32 totalRows, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)
   at PocSys.DAL.tb_POLine_iSales_Upload_DAL.ImportDataFromExcel_DAL(String excelFilePath, String sheetName, String userID, String& ReturnMsg)

Target: Int64 DoubleDateToTicks(Double)

Source: mscorlib
```

About SQL database, now the column SignDate is nvarchar(100), but I already tried with datetime, and didn't works, and it accepts null value.